Mt. 15:21-28 vs. Mt. 10:5 - What was Jesus doing in the region of Tyre and Sidon?

21 Then Jesus went from that place and withdrew to the region of
Tyre and Sidon. 22 And behold, a Canaanite woman of that district came
and called out, “Have pity on me, Lord, Son of David! My daughter is
tormented by a demon.” 23 But he did not say a word in answer to her.
His disciples came and asked him, “Send her away, for she keeps
calling out after us.” 24 He said in reply, “I was sent only to the
lost sheep of the house of Israel.” 25 But the woman came and did
him homage, saying, “Lord, help me.” 26 He said in reply, “It is not
right to take the food of the children and throw it to the dogs.”
27 She said, “Please, Lord, for even the dogs eat the scraps that fall
from the table of their masters.” 28 Then Jesus said to her in
reply, “O woman, great is your faith! Let it be done for you as you
wish.” And her daughter was healed from that hour.

In Matthew 10:5 Jesus directs his disciples: “Do not go into pagan territory or enter a Samaritan town." Yet in Mt. 15 he heals the daughter of a Canaanite woman in the region of Tyre and Sidon - definitely pagan territory. At first Jesus does not respond to her, saying: “I was sent only to the lost sheep of the house of Israel," but when the woman humbly insists, he praises her faith and performs the healing.
A few issues arise from this incident:

Since Jesus says that he was sent only to the lost sheep of the House of Israel, did he travel to this region to spread the Gospel to those Jews who lived there, or for some other reason? If so, what business might he have had there?

Or is it the case that it was OK for disciples to travel to such places as long as Jesus accompanied them, such as in John 4 (the story of the Samaritan woman at the well)?  Or did Jesus relax the proscription against going to pagan territories at some time between Mt. 10 at Mt. 15?



Luke records that Jesus sent the disciples on at least two missionary training tours, of which Matthew only records the first, but with much more detail.  These two training tours appear to be approximately 12 months apart.

First Missionary Training Tour: (Luke 9:1-6, Matt 10:1-11:1) Jesus sends out the 12 with instruction to go only to Jews
Second Missionary Training Tour: (Luke 10:1-12) Jesus sends out the 72 with instruction to go to all towns and cities

[We could add a third "tour" for completeness as recorded in Matt 28:19, 20, Acts 1:7 & 8, where Jesus instructs all disciples to go the ends of the earth.]
Note that in these initial training tours, Jesus lets the disciples into evangelism gently by first sending them to just the peoples with whom they are familiar; that is, they were learning to do evangelism and so initially, they were excused from dealing with cultural differences.  How to deal with cultural and language differences would come later (as in Acts 2 for the language differences).
Thus, the fact that Jesus only sent the initial disciples to their fellow country-men in hardly surprising.  This is not to suggest that Jesus wanted to exclude foreigners; far from it.  Jesus ministered to foreigners on numerous occasions as the OP has documented, such as in Samaria in John 2 and Tyre-Sidon as in Matt 15, etc.  However, the disciples' initial efforts were made a little easier but only reaching out to Jews.


1 This makes sense but I do wonder if it was more along the lines of salvation first being given to the Jews and then the Gentiles... Romans 1:16


@DanFefferman - there was probably an element of that as well especially since it was not really until the conversion of the apostle Paul that the gospel went to the gentiles several years after Jesus' resurrection.  However, Rom 1:16 I have always understood as a simple historical fact that the Jesus, the disciples and most early Christians, (plus the nation of Israel themselves) had the gospel message before the gentiles.  See Rom 11 about the olive tree metaphor.

Re. Rom 1:16 "to the Jew first, and also to the Greek" — Wasn't it simply a matter of practicality in terms of building the Church? The Jews already understood everything but didn't yet believe his message, so they were the obvious people to target for early growth. Only after a significant base of Christians had been established in a community would it be worthwhile expanding to the Gentiles, who did not have the background knowledge and would need a lot of mentoring.

@RayButterworth.... I do see it as being simple. Not only did Jesus forbid his disciples to enter Samaritan towns in Mt. but he declared that he was sent only the lost sheep of the House of Israel... and yet in John's Gospel he leads his disciples into a Samaritan town  quite early in his ministry and witnesses to a woman there - and here he does something similar. But I do think Dottard's answer makes sense.

In short, Jesus sought a much-needed reprieve, both physically and mentally.
In Matthew 14, following the distressing news of John the Baptist execution, Jesus withdrew privately by boat to find solitude (Matthew 14:13). However, the pressing needs of a large crowds who followed Him kept Him engaged, resulting the miraculous "Feeding the Five Thousand". That night, Jesus dismissed everyone and prayed on the mountain alone. He walked on water to reunion with His disciples. When arriving the town, immediately the sicks were brought to him, as well as facing the Pharisees.
Mark portrays a similar sequence of events, with a slight rearrangement. He put the return of the twelve disciples amidst Jesus's narrative, underlining the crucial need for rest not only for Jesus but also for His disciples. Mark 6:31 states: " Then, because so many people were coming and going that they did not even have a chance to eat, he said to them, “Come with me by yourselves to a quiet place and get some rest.”
It becomes apparent that initially, Jesus sought solace in quieter surroundings, but it proved difficult due to the persistent demands of the crowds in need of Him. Consequently, He retreated even further into the Gentile region, seeking a deeper reprieve. While His ministry primarily focused on the Jews, His boundless compassion for all of humanity compelled Him to respond to the needs of both Jews and Gentiles, even in his moments of weariness.

I upvoted this as useful, although I can't really picture Jesus taking his disciples for a vacation in the area of Tyre and Sidon at this stage of his ministry. I picture him as taking only brief respites, climbing local hills in the Galilee at this point.

Indeed it was not a vacation. Jesus was likely in sadness upon hearing about John's execution. Consider His humanity, Jesus would have experienced mental limitations similar to any other man, even though the narrative doesn't explicitly reveal it.

your insight about the death of John and its possible impact on Jesus is appreciated.

Tyre finds 64 mentions in OT and NT put together. Going by those references, including prophecies, we can safely conclude that the region of Tyre and Sidom was friendly with the Jewish people and was involved in trade with them . It is also possible that many exiled Jews resided there, and Jesus was visiting them.Jesus even appreciated the region's potential for salvation when he said:

Woe to you, Chora′zin! woe to you, Beth-sa′ida! for if the mighty works done in you had been done in Tyre and Sidon, they would have repented long ago in sackcloth and ashes.( Mtt 11:21)

